# Can I prune old branches from .git/config

Tags: git

I've noticed that whenever you track a remote branch in git it adds an entry in the project's `.git/config` file. When that branch is deleted, from both the remote and local, it doesn't get deleted from there.

Is there a command to remove old branches from there, or even better, a setting so that they are auto-removed?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly

```
git prune
```

or if you prefer you can have `fetch` perform a prune for you as of git 1.8.5

```
git config fetch.prune true
git fetch
```

Comment: git prune removes the tracking branch, but it doesn't seem to remove the tracking branch's config from .git/config, or if it does, some have been missed somehow, and I have some dangling entries left.

Comment: I think you mean `git fetch --prune` or `git remote prune` here...? (In any case, I use—and recommend—the `fetch.prune true` setting as a `--global` setting.)